# Get rid of Guice Dependency

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have following class

```
  public class TransactionalTest {
    @javax.inject.Inject
    EntityManager em;

    @com.google.inject.persist.Transactional
    public void insertSomeData() {
      Preferences p0 = new Preferences();
      p0.setTemplatename("pref 01");
      em.persist(p0);
    }   
   }
```

I am using javax.inject.Inject instead of com.google.inject.Inject.
What is the correct annotation for Transactional, thus I have no dependencies to Guice?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this dependency in the first place?

Comment: For the same reason I write javax.persistence.EntityManager instead of org.hibernate.ejb.EntitManagerImpl. I like to use the interfaces instead of the concret implementation.

Comment: @Waxolunist But Google Guice doesn't implement a standard API here, unlike Hibernate does with JPA. (Or like Guice does with JSR-330.) There's a [`TransactionalAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/ejb/TransactionManagement.html) annotation in Java EE, but it's part of the EJB API, and Guice Persist isn't an EJB implementation. They *might* support the annotation out of the box, but I wouldn't bet on it. (I don't even think Spring does with its transaction management implementation.)

Comment: Yep, thats the solution. It's not standard. Thx for the help

Answer (score 2):

From my memories, you will have to [write your own](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_151_transactional_interceptors_using) annotation.

However, if you're in a JavaEE system, youc an use EJB [`TransactionAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html). There also exist some CDI extensiosn, like Seam Solder or Apache DeltaSpike that *may* in a distant future provide such code outside of JavaEE containers.

Comment: Seams, I have to live with this if I don't want to write my own.

Comment: @Waxolunist yeah, if you want to use it outside of EJBs, you'll indeed have to use Guice annotation.

Comment: MyFaces CODI provides it as well, if you don't like to use EJBs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/Documentation#Documentation-JPA